# How can I find a file in a directory

Tags: python, search, directory

I need to write code that will search for a file in the same directory as the program itself is saved in. I am limited to some specific lines of code and I cannot use for loops.

The code should ask the user for input, take that input and search it in the directory, and if not in the directory of any other error it must re-prompt the user. I am very new to programming so I don't know how to accomplish this task. Any tips or example codes are extremely helpful and appreciated greatly

The code NEEDS to include:

```
filename = input(msg)
```

and

```
print("That file does not exist.")
```

and ends with

```
return filename
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have to show us some sort of effort in solving the problem. StackOverflow isn't a 'code-order' website. What have you tried? What possible solutions do you think there are? Have you tried looking around for this answer anywhere else?

Comment: `os.listdir('.')` lists files and subdirectories in the current directory. `filename in os.listdir('.')` gets you a bit closer except that it still matches directories and doesn't account for case-insensitive file systems like ntfs on windows.

Comment: hello alex and i know it is not a code order website, however i don't know how to utilize the functions necessary to operate the search. That's why i don't have any sample code. I've looked around and found very specific results that are not related to mine, and since i am not familiar with this topic i wasn't able to utilize the answers there and utilize it to my use. And thanks for the warm welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt exactly what you asked for but it will get you started.

```
import os    #bring in the necessary library to access your specific os

filename = raw_input("Enter file: ")   #get user input

dirList = os.listdir('.')    #get the current directory listing
if filename in dirList:      #if the filename sought was in that dirlist....
    print "file found: " + filename   #display it
else:                            #otherwise...
    print "That file does not exist."
```